# Error during signUp: Error: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error

Tags: node.js, typescript, grpc, grpc-js

I am getting following error when i try to make grpc call using my node client:

```
code: 13,
  details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
```

Following is how am trying to make the call: `SingUpRequest` and `CustomerServiceExternalClient` is imported from my protos

```
 grpcClient: CustomerServiceExternalClient
 constructor(){
this.grpcClient = new CustomerServiceExternalClient(
       'mygrpcserveraddress', 
      ChannelCredentials.createInsecure() 
    )
}

async myfunction() {
const signUpRequest: SignUpRequest = {
      signInAttributeKey: 'somekey',
      signInAttributeValue: '3333333333339', 
      requestMetadata: {}, 
    }

    try {
      const signUpResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.grpcClient.signUp(signUpRequest, (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error)
          } else {
            resolve(response)
          }
        })
      })

      console.log('SignUp successful:', signUpResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during signUp:', error)
      throw error 
    }

}
```

I tried calling grpc function SignUp but it gave me following error:

```
  code: 13,
  details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
```

Note: I have tested the same grpc call using postman using same server address and port and it is working. This error only occur when running my client.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the server using a known working client (e.g. [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl))? This will demonstrate that the server is running correctly, is accessible and responding to a gRPC client with the expected service(s)|method(s)? If you use `gRPCurl` (as a Go binary), you can prefix the command `GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99 GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info grpcurl ...` to enable more extensive logging by the gRPC runtime.

Comment: Are you sure that server is actually serving gRPC on the port you are connecting to?

Comment: i havnt tried with gRPCurl yet. thanks for suggestion will try it now

Comment: server is running fine when tested using postman. I used the same address and port and same grpc signUp call. the error only occurs when i make grpc call using my client